# GWT 2.7 DatePicker Left/Right Scroll Arrows Not Working in Chrome

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, datepicker

I am on Chrome 51.0.2704.103m and 51.0.2704.106m and noticed that the left and right arrows to scroll through a GWT 2.7 DatePicker Calendar not longer work. When I click the button, absolutely nothing happens. This was working for me with no issues about a week ago. JavaScript doesn't appear to be throwing any errors.

[image]

Comment: Works fine here using Chrome 51.0.2704.103m and GWT 2.7.0

Comment: Also tested it now using Chrome 51.0.2704.106m. Works just fine.

Comment: Baz - Thanks. It's happening sporadically now. Trying to nail down what potential outside variables that might be causing it to happen.